# How to run sql query with bit field when using FromSql

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.2

I have this query:

```
return await this.DbContext.SearchRequestInfos.FromSql(
    $@"{SqlStrings.SP.SearchSearchRequests} 
    @searchRequestId = {input.SearchRequestId},
    @customerId = {input.CustomerId},
    @customerName = {input.CustomerName},
    @code = {input.Code},
    @description = {input.Description},
    @isGeneric = {input.IsGeneric},
    @isActive = {input.IsActive}
    "
                ).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

which creates this sql:

```
Executed DbCommand (69ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 4000), @p1='?', @p2='?', @p3='?', @p4='?', @p5='?', @p6='?' (DbType = Boolean), @p7='?' (DbType = Boolean)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
Portal>       @p0 
Portal>                         @searchRequestId = @p1,
Portal>                         @customerId = @p2,
Portal>                         @customerName = @p3,
Portal>                         @code = @p4,
Portal>                         @description = @p5,
Portal>                         @isGeneric = @p6,
Portal>                         @isActive = @p7
```

The issue is that @isGeneric and @isActive are bit fields, but the value is not getting used.  In other words, the value should be true, which should be translated to 1, but it is not.

Is this a bug in EF Core, or am I doing something wrong?

The workaround is to add a property to convert the value to an int, and then the SQL works as expected.

```
public int? IsGenericBit { get {
            if(this.IsGeneric.HasValue) return this.IsGeneric.Value ? 1 : 0;
                return null;
            } }

public int? IsActiveBit { get {
             if (this.IsActive.HasValue) return this.IsActive.Value ? 1 : 0;
                return null;
            } }


Portal>       Executed DbCommand (63ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 4000), @p1='?', @p2='?', @p3='?', @p4='?', @p5='?', @p6='?' (DbType = Int32), @p7='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
Portal>       @p0 
Portal>                         @searchRequestId = @p1,
Portal>                         @customerId = @p2,
Portal>                         @customerName = @p3,
Portal>                         @code = @p4,
Portal>                         @description = @p5,
Portal>                         @isGeneric = @p6,
Portal>                         @isActive = @p7
```

Note that that it specificies @6 and @7 as Int32 although they are actual bit in the database.

So the question is: Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: Are you sure this works at all? Using `{SqlStrings.SP.SearchSearchRequests}` inside interpolated string will cause EF Core to put the name of the SP in a parameter `@p0` which makes the whole SQL invalid.

Comment: Yes, it works fine.  Have done many times successfully.